# Standard deviation is zero for statsBy function

Tags: r, error-handling, correlation, multi-level, psych

I am currently working on multilevel data. Therefore I decided to use the function `statsBy` to calcuate correlations. Correlations are calculated but R keeps on sending this ERROR message "the standard deviation is zero for statsBy function".

I already looked at the SD of all variables and non is zero.

Does anyone have an idea where this error could come from?

```
library(psych)

cormatrix1 <- statsBy(dat_all[c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "neuroticism", "f", "g", "h","i", "j", "k","l","m", "n", "o", "p","q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")], c(dat_all$ID), cors = TRUE, cor="cor", method="pearson", use="pairwise", 
                      poly=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE,alpha=.05,minlength=5)

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In cor(x[-gr], use = use, method = method) : the standard deviation is zero
2: In cor(x[-gr], use = use, method = method) : the standard deviation is zero
...
50: In cor(x[-gr], use = use, method = method) : the standard deviation is zero
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please edit your code to include library(psych) if that is the package that has your version of statsBy. Can you please edit your post to include the dataset.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Sadly I am not allowed to upload my dataset due to sensitive personal data.